# Math equations in database and json response

Tags: mysql, json, database

Kindly let me know how shall I achieve the following stuff

1. what type(blob,text) is preferred in database to store all kind of special symbols? math equations having square root, quadratic equations as shown [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathType#mediaviewer/File:MathType60.png) ,physics equations etc
2. how to enter such data to database ? is there any tool which I shall use to enter any kind of data ? I tried with some rich text editors , but they add all html tags with actual content ( those html tags doesn't work for mobile apps )
3. Using RESTFul services I have to return such equations to mobile applications as JSON , how to send such data in JSON ? do they retain their original form while converting between json to string and string to json ?

So i want to enter certain data manually to Database, so which tool do u suggest ?

Note: I am using mysql database

Comment: Are you referring to Unicode symbols for these or something like LaTex which is rendered on the web page?

Comment: my question is how to store Math and physics equations in database (quadratic equations, greek symbols etc) and how to do such data entry to database ? which tool can be used ? phpmyadmin doesn't work such such formulae and special symbols

Comment: @shree.pat18 kindly check my question, I have edited it with another requirement thanks

Comment: Refer to [How to save math equations to database..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32579105/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the math equations using a MathML editor and then you can store the generated MathML as a text in your MySQL db.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use those functions that are [available in mysql by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html)? You need to start a query anyway and should you try to use php, then Parser might do the trick and deal with this issue instead of throwing all in the database. Much more convenient and less overhead.

Comment: I think u didn't get my question, I have to show the same equations to users in mobile application

Comment: But why do you want to use a database and not some file in which you hardcore the equations and query them through a function for instance? Use a proper encoding and then it is ready to go. It is faster and easier to implement. With regular expressions you can merge the results together in a nice and easy kind of way. A small parser-function can be of help as well. ... out of curiosiyt, on what plattform do you want to run the programm?

Comment: I hv many other stuff to be shown and the services should be developed for the same. Web services will be deployed in cloud. hope you got my exact requirement